# PHP & MySQL: Making a row in table to a variable specified by a $_POST['username']

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
//The victim's name, taken from a textfield
$victim = $_POST['username'];
//The ammount to be withdrawn from the user
$ammount = 2000;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money = money-$ammount WHERE username = '$victim'");
echo "You stole $ammount from $victim";
} else {
echo "Write the username of the person you're trying to steal money from..";
}

?>
```

This is my code so far, I am trying to figure out a way I can get the ammount not to be a static $2000, but lets say 15% of the ammount that is in the 'money' row in the users table, where the username is the same as the variable $victim.

I'm thinking I'am going to need a variable called $victimsMoney, that will hold the ammount that is in the field from the mysql table>'users'>column>'money', specifield to the username that is the same as $victim.

How do I make a variable of the 'money' column, where the username is $victim (the username the person typed in)?

My own suggestion, that does not work:

```
$victimsMoney = mysql_query("SELECT money FROM users WHERE username = '$victim'");
```

Comment: When you first fetch a value/record. modify it and then re-enter it you have to take care of concurrency/race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$victimsMoney = mysql_query("SELECT money FROM users WHERE username = '".$victim."'");
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($victimsMoney)){
                echo $fetch['money'];
}
```

make sure you escape any variables. otherwise php will parse it as a string :)

try this and in the future read the manual, it's very helpful :)

mysqli_fetch is going to become deprecated.
Heres the manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php